# pg_dump generates invalid SQL command

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

When I run pg_dump on my database, it's converting one of my views (orders_plus) to a table, and then creating a rule that I guess puts it back to the equivalent of a view.  That seems to be OK (though strange).  However, right after the 'CREATE RULE' it puts this line:

```
ALTER VIEW orders_plus SET ();
```

That's not a valid command, and so I get an error when recovering the database.

Comment: Postgres and pg_dump version? Also can you show the view definition?

Comment: It's 9.2.1, using the Server version on Mac.  When I created it I used a "create view" command, but the pg_dump wrote out a 'create table' command for the view instead.  Which are you asking for?

Comment: What version of `pg_dump` are you using? Mac has an old version of Postgres installed by default and you might be using old version of `pg_dump`.

Comment: 9.2.1 - I'm using the binaries inside /Application/Server.app

Comment: @Gargoyle What's "Server"? Link? Where's it from? Please tell me there isn't *another* weird custom PostgreSQL packaging for Mac OS X now..

Comment: When you install the server version of mac os x you get that application, and it includes the newer versions of the postgres binaries (9.2.1 vs. 9.1.5)

Comment: @CraigRinger: This time it looks like it was a PostgreSQL bug fixed in v9.2.2, and not some weird MacPackaging ;)  I added a separate answer just in case there are some v9.2.1 installations out there forced to migrate the next year. If they haven't already upgraded to v9.2.18'ish, some might jump straight to newer versions and hit this issue when upgrading.

Comment: Actually, it was weird Mac packaging too. Apple for some time bundled PostgreSQL as part of their OS X Server application `Server.app`. I think they continue to do so, but now they're (correctly) putting it on a non-default port with a non-default `unix_sockets_directory` so you can't connect to it accidentally and it's just an invisible part of the system.

Answer (score 1):

pg_dump should never do this.  This is a problem with your server or your client.  Since you got this from Apple and it may be customized follow up with them.

My guess is that one of the `pg_get_*` functions is failing.  This could be an issue with data in your system tables or it could be issues with the server-side functions.  But I have never seen anything like this before anywhere else so Apple would be the place to start.

Answer (score 1):

... 3 years later ...

Seems you stumbled upon a bug in v9.2.1, which was fixed in v9.2.2.

See [v9.2.2 release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/release-9-2-2.html):

> Fix pg_dump for views with circular dependencies and no relation
>   options (Tom Lane)
>
> The previous fix to dump relation options when a view is involved in a
>   circular dependency didn't work right for the case that the view has
>   no options; it emitted ALTER VIEW foo SET () which is invalid syntax.

I recently noticed the exact same issue when restoring/migrating a production database. I used an older version of pg_dump than the database by mistake;)

```
psql:dump.sql:27821784: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: ALTER VIEW <viewname> SET ();
```

The problem went away when using pg_dump v9.2.6.

For completeness, here's some software info: Postgres version 9.2.6 GNU/Linux 2.6.18-406.el5 #1 SMP Fri May 1 10:37:57 EDT 2015 x86_64. Red Hat Enterprise release 5.11 (Tikanga).